# SHA512 Hashing MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hash, password-hash

Apologies for the simple question but i am still learning php/mysql

I'm attempting to hash passwords on registration, which works, however once the hashing is complete the user cannot log in with their password. Below is a small snippet of my variables

```
  $password = hash('sha512',$_POST['password']); 
  $confirmPassword = hash('sha512',$_POST['confirmPassword']);
```

->So, the password is matched with confirm password and then they are compared using Javascript and PHP, if they match the data gets inserted into the database. So why isnt it allowing the user to log in?

Currently in my Database my password column is set to CHAR(128) if that helps?

Comment: Basically you are asking us to debug your code, which is not even present - I mean the code that is doing the logging part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your password column is too small.Do a simple:

`echo sizeof(hash('sha512',$_POST['confirmPassword']));`

and get the right size of your database column.

Comment: Thank you, it seems i made a careless mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to hash passwords this way with a single unsalted SHA512. PHP offers dedicated functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to do this job correctly:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($_POST['password'], $existingHashFromDb);
```

To check whether the password and its confirmation are equal, you should compare them directly (plaintext), *before* you calculate the hash.

It is recommended to use a database field of type varchar(255) to store this hash, to be future proof.